# How to use sqlalchemy.orm.Query.with_for_update()

Tags: python, sql, sqlalchemy

the following is taken from the SQLAlchemy docs:

> method **sqlalchemy.orm.Query.with_for_update(read=False, nowait=False, of=None, skip_locked=False, key_share=False)**
> return a new Query with the specified options for the FOR UPDATE clause.
> The behavior of this method is identical to that of GenerativeSelect.with_for_update(). When called with no arguments, the resulting SELECT statement will have a FOR UPDATE clause appended. When additional arguments are specified, backend-specific options such as FOR UPDATE NOWAIT or LOCK IN SHARE MODE can take effect.

This is all the docs mention about `with_for_update()`. What I want to know is what each of these parameters mean. I have a table *Ticket* and each ticket could be either available to be purchased or already purchased. The process of purchasing a ticket could take sometime as it depends on external APIs and payment gateways. So what I aim to do is lock some rows once payment starts and update them and then release the lock. However there are other queries that are running on the table to determine ticket availability (counts rows that are not paid) so I want these queries to skip a row if it's locked without counting it (so it shouldn't read a locked row). However I can't guess what each of `with_for_update()`'s flags do and I can't find proper documentation for it.

I haven't tried experimenting with the parameters as it is difficult to setup and simulate a scenario where I would know for sure what effect each parameter has.

If you could help clear out the confusion by directing me to a documentation or explaining what parameters to use to get to where I'm going it would be helpful.

Comment: thank you that helped a lot, I found out I was digging through version 1.4's documentation which i didn't notice despite there being a massive red banner on top saying LEGACY VERSION, but anyways thank you!